# AWS Serverless Image Handler not generating cloudfront resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used this guide to deploy Serverless Image Handler:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/welcome.html

The guide tells you that after the stac creation is finished, you should go to the outputs tab and get the partial url for the cloudfront resource:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EtdPZzkoEbOsYqoeVPelbFeuzS8eiveq

But here's what I see:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nnzFwmlaEp-0ZaPrm6bG3ZsSo_e3lBHA/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, there is no cloudfront resource, just the one for the demo UI, which is actually stored in another bucket, it's not my origin bucket.

The result is that I can use the demo ui perfectly, but there is no way to access my original bucket. It seems like there was a problem with the step of creating the cloudfront resource for my origin bucket.

I will appreaciate any kind of help. Maybe the guide is outdated and there is some new steps that I should follow.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was outdated. To be able to use your own cloudfront resource, you need to deploy the stack without the demo ui.